octet-stream memory leaking when using Bun and Elysia
So a few weeks ago, I ported my app that uses NodeJS to Bun (and also moved from Express to Elysia). However, it seems that it's heavily memory leaking when there is a lot of traffic going on.
memory usage after a day
Seems like the issue happens on the GET /file/ endpoint. I've tried running the garbage collector manually with Bun.gc() every second, but the memory was still continuing to increase without being freed the more I used the endpoint.
I got suggested that I should (re)use pipe() instead of directly returning the response, however I'm not really sure on how I'm supposed to do that with Elysia.
potentially affected lines
If you want to look more into this, you can check out the repository here.
